# django update view and passing context

Tags: python, django, view, django-context

I have a update view:

```
class GeneralUserUpdateView(UpdateView):

    model = GeneralUser
    form_class = GeneralUserChangeForm
    template_name = "general_user_change.html"

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(GeneralUserUpdateView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, pk, username):

        self.pk = pk
        self.username = username
        self.gnu = GeneralUser.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        #form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
        return super(GeneralUserUpdateView, self).post(request, pk)

    def form_valid(self, form, *args, **kwargs):
        self.gnu.username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        self.gnu.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        self.gnu.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        self.gnu.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        self.gnu.address = form.cleaned_data['address']
        self.gnu.save()

        return redirect("user_profile", self.pk, self.username)
```

Here in this view I want to pass a context like:

```
context['picture'] = GeneralUser.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
```

I did trying get_context_data but I cant access pk in there.. 
Am I doing the update right?? How can I pass that context in there??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be overriding `post` at all. All of that logic should happen in `get_context_data`.

In fact, none of your overrides are needed. Everything that you do in `form_valid` will be done already by the standard form save. And overriding `dispatch` just to call the superclass is pointless.

Your view should look like this only, with no overridden methods at all:

```
class GeneralUserUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = GeneralUser
    form_class = GeneralUserChangeForm
    template_name = "general_user_change.html"
    context_object_name = 'picture'
```

(although it seems a little odd that you want to refer to an instance of GeneralUser as "picture").

**Edit** to redirect to a specific URL, you can define `get_success_url`:

```
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse("user_profile", self.kwargs['pk'], self.kwargs['username'])
```

Comment: and what about redirect ?? How can I get pk and username while redirecting ?? How to use that ??